# Multiple docker-composes access single volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two separate docker-composes and I want them to have access to the same volume but I'm not sure the best approach for this.

This is a roughly how I am trying to make this work:

```
version: '3'

services:
  container1:
    volumes:
      - myvolume

volumes:
  myvolume:
```

```
version: '3'

services:
  container2:
    volumes:
      - myvolume
```

I have one docker compose which defines ands uses a volume and I want to have the other docker compose to also have access to the volume.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
version: '3'

services:
  container1:
    volumes:
      - internal-volume-name

volumes:
  internal-volume-name:
    name: external-volume-name
```

```
version: '3'

services:
  container2:
    volumes:
      - internal-volume-name

volumes:
  internal-volume-name:
    external: true
    name: external-volume-name
```

Where the volume is created, it must be given a name (external-volume-name).
When you want to reference it from another docker-compose, you must specify `external: true` and then specify the same given name (`name: external-volume-name`)